# From SQL Foreign keys to Realm References?

Tags: json, realm

We have a PostgreSQL server-side DB. We download table rows to the tablet through JSON strings. Now we are migrating to Realm and are now facing the Foreign Keys problem right now. How does Realm manage this?. I mean, our shema has a lot of references in many different tables so we cannot download a single huge JSON with a N-th level of depth containing all nested references.

Therefore, how is this achieved?. Do we need to download all JSON for each table and then insert they by hand taking into account the foreign keys from the SQL table to stablish objects references?, Os is this done somehow interanlly by Realm?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28255682/4519059) can help you ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Joe from Realm here.

You are correct, you will need to pull down the JSON then build out your objects manually on the client side. Realm is object graph based so you link objects with objects directly!

For example if a person has many dogs, on the server you should retrieve the person and all the dogs they own and build your objects with that. This format will make it much easier to import these objects into the database. The only reason you will still need foreign keys is so that you can sync things up with the server if you choose to go that route. NoSQL is all about linking objects together which makes things more natural to think about and use.